# Filtering a DataFrame based on two logical conditions, first one numpy array values, second one current day based

Tags: python, pandas

The following is just a working example.

I have a DataFrame containings a monotonous growing function.
Some of the values are actuals, some are forecasted.

I need to filter specific actuals values based on a set of milestones and I have to avoid to take forecasted values from the dataframe

I created this following script.
It works, but I think is not so much pythoninc.

I am a self taught and my working eviroment is `Google Colab`

Expected Output

- I would avoid the `for loop` and the `if` condition
- Understand if there is room of improvement in the code quality

  ```
  #importing libraries 
  import pandas as pd 
  import numpy as np
  import datetime

  #working code mock-up
  th_array = np.arange(0, 11000, 1000)
  cumulated_array = np.arange(0, 5000, 185)

  df_index = pd.date_range(end = "20/04/2021", 
                           periods = len(cumulated_array))
  df = pd.DataFrame(data = cumulated_array,index = df_index, 
                  columns = ["cumulated"])



  df_filtered = pd.DataFrame()
  current_day =  pd.to_datetime(datetime.date.today())

  #filtering loop
  for y in th_array:
    x = df[(df['cumulated'] > y) & (df.index < current_day)]
    if x.empty is False:
        df_filtered = df_filtered.append(x.iloc[0])
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to refactor the loop is to locate the desired rows with [**`idxmax()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and then index them in one shot:

```py
df = df[df.index < current_day]
th_array = th_array[th_array < df.cumulated.max()]

indexes = pd.DataFrame(df.cumulated.values[:, None] > th_array).idxmax()
df.iloc[indexes]

#             cumulated
# 2021-03-25        185
# 2021-03-30       1110
# 2021-04-04       2035
# 2021-04-10       3145
```

---

#### Explanation

First, keep only the rows before `current_day`:

```py
df = df[df.index < current_day]

#             cumulated
# 2021-03-24          0
# 2021-03-25        185
# ...
# 2021-04-10       3145
# 2021-04-11       3330
```

And keep only the `th_array` values less than `cumulated.max()`:

```py
th_array = th_array[th_array < df.cumulated.max()]

# array([   0, 1000, 2000, 3000])
```

Then use [array broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy) to build a boolean matrix of `cumulated > th_array` where rows correspond to `cumulated` and columns to `th_array`:

```py
valid = pd.DataFrame(df.cumulated.values[:, None] > th_array)

#         0      1      2      3
# 0   False  False  False  False
# 1    True  False  False  False
# 2    True  False  False  False
# 3    True  False  False  False
# 4    True  False  False  False
# 5    True  False  False  False
# 6    True   True  False  False
# 7    True   True  False  False
# 8    True   True  False  False
# 9    True   True  False  False
# 10   True   True  False  False
# 11   True   True   True  False
# 12   True   True   True  False
# 13   True   True   True  False
# 14   True   True   True  False
# 15   True   True   True  False
# 16   True   True   True  False
# 17   True   True   True   True
# 18   True   True   True   True
```

So for each column (`th_array`), we want the first `True` row (`cumulated`). These can be found with [**`idxmax()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html). Since `False` is 0 and `True` is 1, all the `True` indexes are tied for the max, and the first one wins the tiebreaker:

```py
indexes = valid.idxmax()

# 0     1
# 1     6
# 2    11
# 3    17
# dtype: int64
```

Then just `iloc` these `indexes` for the final filtered `df`:

```py
df.iloc[indexes]

#             cumulated
# 2021-03-25        185
# 2021-03-30       1110
# 2021-04-04       2035
# 2021-04-10       3145
```

---

#### Timing

For the sample data, the indexing method runs ~11 times faster than looping+appending:

```
>>> %timeit iloc(df, th_array)
989 µs ± 15.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit loop(df, th_array)
10.9 ms ± 202 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Testing functions for reference:

```py
def iloc(df, th_array):
    df = df[df.index < current_day]
    th_array = th_array[th_array < df.cumulated.max()]
    indexes = pd.DataFrame(df.cumulated.values[:, None] > th_array).idxmax()
    return df.iloc[indexes]

def loop(df, th_array):
    df_filtered = pd.DataFrame()
    for y in th_array:
        x = df[(df['cumulated'] > y) & (df.index < current_day)]
        if x.empty is False:
            df_filtered = df_filtered.append(x.iloc[0])
    return df_filtered
```

Comment: maybe is a silly question, but why you also specify `None`  inside `df.cumulated.values[:, None]` ?